# Fermat Primality Test failure in C

Tags: c, testing, primes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

#define MAXNUM 2000000000
#define MINNUM 1990000001
#define MAXTRIES 10

unsigned long long b, e, m, result; 

int modulo(b, e, m) 
{
    result = 1;

    while(e > 0)
    {
        if(e % 2 == 1)
        {
            result = (result * b);
        } 

        b = (b * b) % m;
        e = e / 2;
    }

    return result % m;
}

int isPrime(n) 
{
    unsigned long long a; 

    int i; 

    for(i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        a = rand() % (n - 1) + 1;
        if(modulo(a, n - 1, n) != 1)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

int main() 
{
    unsigned int prime = 0;
    unsigned int flag = 0;
    unsigned int tries;
    unsigned int start;
    long curtime;
    unsigned long long p;

    curtime = time(NULL);
    srand((unsigned int) curtime);
    printf("Checking range [1990000001, 2000000000] for prime numbers.\n");
    if(MINNUM % 2 == 0)
    {            
        start = MINNUM + 1;      
    }
    else
    {
        start = MINNUM;    
    }

    printf("Trying Fermat test with seed %ld \n\n",curtime);
    prime = 0;

    for(tries = 1; tries <= MAXTRIES; tries++)
    {
        clock_t tic = clock();
        for(p = start; p <= MAXNUM; p += 2)
        {
            if(isPrime(p))
                prime++;
        } 

        clock_t toc = clock();
        printf("Probabilistic algorithm: Found %ld primes in %f seconds.(tries = %d)\n", prime, (double)(toc - tic) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC,tries);
        prime = 0;
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

So the problem is that the algorithm finds in every try 5000000 prime numbers when it should find around 466646 with some deviation. Which means that in every try it should find a number of primes close to the one mentioned above.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @UniCell It obviously finds the wrong results and i can't figure why it does so. Any recommendations on fixing this problem?

Comment: Are you sure that `result=(result*b)` doesn't overflow? If you return `result%m` at the end of this function, then why don't you do `result=(result*b)%m` instead? Also (and regardless of that), why have you declared it as a global variable (especially due to the fact that you're using a local variable with an identical name in one of your other functions)???

Comment: Not so obvious if you don't write what is the actual output, what it should output, also have you tried using a debugger to "step by step" through your code to see what's wrong?

Comment: @barakmanos how can i prevent it from overflowing?

Comment: See my extended comment.

Comment: @ryyker i am now thinking that it might be due to overflow. But can't find a solution.

Comment: Well, the overflow part is a problem, but you have greater problems:

1. Your function parameters don't have an type `int modulo(b, e, m)` should be something like `int modulo(unsigned long long b, unsigned long long e, unsigned long long m)`

2.I believe you think that the variables inside the functions are the same with the variables declared globally.Wrong! The `b, e, m` inside of function `int modulo(b, e, m)` are not the same with `unsigned long long b, e, m, result;`

Comment: Your code is not compilable, you can't implement a function with something like `int modulo(b,e,m){...}`. Some of your text is not properly indented. Those global variables should most certainly be local in function `modulo`. I think you should put a little more effort into your question if you're expecting people to put effort answering it.

Comment: Regarding only the potential overflow problem:  Range of `unsigned long long` is ***[0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx)***, check `b` as it approaches, and handle it.  Since `b` is growing exponentially, it is likely that overflow could occur.  But agree with other commenters, you should work your code to provide a ***[small, compilable segment of code, with only the relevant parts to address your issue](http://sscce.org/)***.  If you do that, you will likely find the issue yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the main problem is caused by integer overflows in the `modulo()` function. Specifically, `result=(result*b)` is going to overflow quite regularly. You need to store these variables in 64-bit unsigned integers, and calculate the modulus of this result every time.

This will work (with a few minor corrections elsewhere):

```
#include <inttypes.h>

#define MAXNUM 2000000000
#define MINNUM 1990000001
#define MAXTRIES 10


uint64_t modulo(uint64_t b, uint64_t e, uint64_t m){
    uint64_t result=1;
    while(e>0){
        if(e%2==1){
            result=(result*b)%m;
        }
        b=(b*b)%m;
        e=e/2;
    }
    return result%m;
}
```

Result:

```
Checking range [1990000001, 2000000000] for prime numbers.
Trying Fermat test with seed 1416322197 

Probabilistic algorithm: Found 466646 primes in 5.157485 seconds.(tries=1)
```

Comment: actually it can work without using the <inttypes.h> library using the unsigned long long type for the modulo function and for its arguments. Thanks though!